# Automatic Bean Creation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Question: will using

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Bean bean = (Bean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{bean}", Bean.class);
```

cause a new Bean to be instantiated each time the code runs through these statements? Or will it simply refer to the same instance initially created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only create one if not already created yet in the current request/session/application.